# resizing Recovery partition after a warranty service

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, asus-laptop

I sent my Asus K52Je to the warranty service last month, for a HD issue.

When returned, the HD was strangely partitioned:

[image: Screenshot]

Now, the Disk 0 has:
- a first (hidden) and not recognized partition: a 336 GB (!) RECOVERY;
- C:\ is the 116 GB NTFS
- D:\ is the 13.6 GB NTFS.

Should I resize the RECOVERY partition without any problem??
And after that, could I extend the C:\ partition? (I don't want to lose my licence and prefer not to use the 9-DVD-recovery tool...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you do anything make sure you have a [system image](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/4241/how-to-create-a-system-image-in-windows-7/) and recovery disk in case anything goes wrong.

It looks as if there is nothing on the the recovery partition - if that is the case I would be tempted to delete it and then increase the size of the OS partition.

You could try doing this with the disk manager in windows but might be better off with [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) which is open source. I'd also verify with GParted that your various partitions look the same as disk management reports - It looks a little odd for windows.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do the resize:

- create a recovery disk for your laptop
- backup up all your important files like music, photos, videos etc on to an external hard disk
- once all that is done delete all partitions
- use your factory recovery disk to reinstall everything to factory defaults
- then resize your partition the way you like and don't resize the recovery partition